# Is $x^3+x^2+x+1$ the same as $x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$x^3+x^2+x+1\equiv (x+1)(x^2+1) \pmod 2$, so $x\equiv1$ is the root of multiplicity $3$. Thus we can rewrite the polynomial as $(x+1)^3$. But is this the same as just $x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$? I'm not so sure, because the multiplicity of the roots is different in the two cases.

A clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x]?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a distinction that must be made in these types of questions:

Are you talking about the function or the polynomial?

As functions on $\mathbb{Z}/2$, $x+1$ and $(x+1)^3\equiv x^3+x^2+x+1$ are identical.  If you take a field extension of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, then you may find that $x+1$ and $(x+1)^3$ are different functions.

However, as polynomials, $x+1$ and $(x+1)^3$ are very different.  The difference is that $x+1$ and $(x+1)^3$ have different algebraic properties in the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/2)[x]$.  For example $x+1$ is irreducible while $(x+1)^3$ is not irreducible.  If you were to take quotients by the ideals that these generate, the quotient by $\langle x+1\rangle$ is a field (it's actually $\mathbb{Z}/2$) while the quotient by $\langle (x+1)^3\rangle$ has zero divisors.

The distinction is: do you treat a polynomial as just the values that arise after plugging in or do you look at the algebraic properties of the polynomial in the ring of polynomials.

Comment: Polynomial. But is a polynomial not a function?

Comment: In what sense are they very different? They only have roots of different multiplicities over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @sequence for one thing, the ideals they generate are very different (one properly contains the other)

Comment: @Mark Do you mean that $(x+1)^3$ reduces to $(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)$, which is then irreducible?

Comment: @sequence A product of irreducible elements is not irreducible.  You mean that $(x+1)^3$ is a product of three irreducible elements ...

Comment: @sequence I mean there is a containment of ideals $\langle (x+1)^3\rangle\subseteq\langle(x+1)\rangle$.  Just like how in $k[x]$ the polynomials $x$ and $x^3$ are different, in part because the ideals $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle x^3\rangle$ are different.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Right, I mean this is a complete factorization of $(x+1)^3$.